# WPF: Changing the layout of Tabs in TabPanel

Tags: wpf, layout, tabcontrol, tabpanel, itemspanel

Instead of at the top I wan't my tabs on the left side. I changed the template for the the TabControl so that the TabPanel would appear in first column and the second column would host the content.

Problem is I'm not sure how I change the TabPanel's layout so the tabs appear stacked vertically.

I know in normal ItemsControl objects its the ItemsPanel that I should change. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out

Comment: Yeah seen that and it helped me when I first started working with tabs. However there is no mention there on the layout of the Tabs themselves. I'm not talking about the content in the header or the panel that opens up when selected but the TabItems theselves I wan't to reorder them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about showing your TabItem's header to the left vertically. Take a look at the [TabStripPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.tabstripplacement.aspx) property. You can set it to left to achieve what you want.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
    ...
    ...
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I mean though I thought I would have to go change the ControlTemplate for this. However I wan't more control as I wan't them to go bottom up ( start at the left-bottom and go up ) and perhaps wan't the to wrap when not selected ( I'm experimenting with a look and selected tabs are much bigger then unselected ).

Comment: @Ingó Vals: If you want to customize it, then you can make use of TabItem's Template or HeaderTemplate property.

Comment: Hmm no I doubt it can be changed at the TabItem template. I mean I wan't the tabs to appear at the bottom left instead of top left.

I was thinking that like when you have a ItemsControl you can change how things appear in it's itemsPanel property, isn't there something similiar with TabControl/TabPanel.